# Setting date_popup year range to more than the 3 years default in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, datetime, javascript

I have a custom module and using date_popup. Currently the popup only shows a 3 year range in the date popup.

```
  $form['startdate'] = array(
    '#type'       =>  'date_popup',
    '#title'      =>  'From',
    '#default_value'  =>  filter_get('browse-startdate'),
    '#date_format'    =>  'Y-m-d',
  );
```

What is needed to make the range higher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following option in the array:

```
    '#date_year_range' => '-8:+8'
```

That goes up to 8 years or more. Generally you don't use minDate as that only goes back up to 3 years only.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work backend wise like in my case (embedding user_register_form with date fields inside a custom build multistep form), you can alter these settings in javascript :

```
var fixDatepickerYearRange = function() {
        $('.field-widget-date-popup').find("input").datepicker({
          yearRange: "-100:+0",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
      };
```

Just run it from document.load or Drupal.behaviors.
More info : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange